# When would an ActiveRecord relationship not be dependent: :destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I often see this code for a one-to-many model association:

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  #...
end
```

My question is, do you ever have any situation where you DON'T need
to specify `dependent: :destroy`? Wouldn't that make your data wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The best reason I know of for not destroying dependents is that more than one 'parent' model `has_one` or `has_many` children. For example, an education application might have a `has_many` relationship between a family and the children in the family, and also have a `has_many` relationship between classes and children. If a class was cancelled you wouldn't want to delete the children who had signed up for it.

Every business application I've ever seen doesn't really delete anything. If an account or an order or something is canceled it's not deleted, but put into a canceled state. That sidesteps this question entirely: it doesn't matter whether you delete through the relationship, because you never delete the parent.

Comment: You could say that `dependent: :destroy` is actually flipping the switch on the order or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For many instances you do want to destroy associated results upon deleting their associated parent however in many areas you do not such as banking transactions etc.  For example, if you had an ecommerce site and had user's create accounts then they will certainly have orders tied to those accounts.  When the user decides they no longer want to keep their account they may delete it however you certainly don't want to destroy it's associated orders even though those orders "belonged_to" an account.  Deleting those orders could expose you to many potential issues.

Comment: True, although in that situation it's more common to _deactivate_ the account, e.g. by flipping a boolean flag.